# How to serve SPA in one separate route in Express multipage app?

Tags: node.js, vue.js, express, single-page-application, multi-page-application

Let's say I have a blog and it's a normal Express multipage app. Now I would like to have a blog content manager as SPA with Vue.js.

I want to serve this app from a single route e.g. https://myapp/admin/dashboard
while the rest is a plain multipage express app (same server).

How to setup something like this in express and vue?

Answer (score 2):

There are three possible strategies:

- either you serve everything under a common path to the SPA with something like

  ```js
  app.get("/spa/*", spa);
  app.get("/spa", spa);
  ```

  In this case the client-side app will have to know its prefix because it will have to prefix all its links, ie it will have to send you to `/spa` when it wants to send you home. Both Vue and React Router support this via an option.
- either you use URL fragments, ie hash links of the form `/spa#sublink`

  In this case Express sees a single route:

  ```js
  app.get("/spa", spa);
  ```

  The application doesn't need to know its prefix, you can relocate it, it always sends you to a relative link like `href="#sublink`. The downside is that you can't have multiple levels.
- or you use query arguments like `/spa?item=sublink`

  This is probably the worst way to do it, since it combines the downsides of all other methods

If you are not sure, the second method is probably the way to go - it doesn't require any special setup.

Comment: "In this case spa will have to know its prefix because it will have to prefix all its links" - this sound ambiguous, it looks like you mean that client-side app is supposed to be aware of the prefix as well, while `spa` refers to Express middleware in this snippet

Comment: I agree, I reworded the sentence